# Too many threads used in scVI-tools, scvi.model.SCVI.train()

Tags: python

I am using scvi-tools to integrate samples.
I restricted usage of threads by "scvi.settings.num_threads = 10" and even "torch.set_num_threads(10)",but scvi.model.SCVI.train command uses as many as threads as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB6WJ.png)

Is there any help to restrict the threads usage?

```
scvi.model.SCVI.setup_anndata(adata_scvi, layer="counts", batch_key=batch_key)
model_scvi = scvi.model.SCVI(adata_scvi)
model_scvi.train()
```

Here's the code I use.

Global seed set to 123

GPU available: False, used: False
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs

Comment: Scvi uses PyTorch internally - [this thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/975) says that sometimes PyTorch doesn't respect the thread setting and that setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` can help. Can you set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=10` and report whether that helps?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I set the environment variable **OMP_NUM_THREADS=10**, but still same. I'v already use the command **torch.set_num_threads(10)**, and this still same.